# Using Photoresistor And analogRead() Value

Tags: arduino

I have a photoresistor connected and I am reading values between 0-1023 just fine. But, *what* is that a measure of? Is it proportional to the resistance or the current or the voltage? I have it reading about 1020 with ambient light (which is, to me, dark-ish). When I hit it with a red laser it drops to around 210.

Hardware details:
I do not have data sheet on photoresistor - I pulled it out of a busted night light.
Resistor in  circuit is 220 ohm.

Schematic:
R = 220 ohm, PR = photoresitor

```
5V--R--A0pin
       --PR--GND
```

I am using [SimPlot](http://www.negtronics.com/simplot) and this is my code:

```
int lightPin = 0;
int buffer[20];

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
 int data1;
 int light = analogRead(lightPin);
 data1 = light;
 plot(data1);
}

void plot(int data1)
{
  int pktSize;

  buffer[0] = 0xCDAB;             //SimPlot packet header. Indicates start of data packet
  buffer[1] = 1*sizeof(int);      //Size of data in bytes. Does not include the header and size fields
  buffer[2] = data1;

  pktSize = 2 + 2 + (1*sizeof(int)); //Header bytes + size field bytes + data

  //IMPORTANT: Change to serial port that is connected to PC
  Serial.write((uint8_t * )buffer, pktSize);
}
```

Comment: It depends completely on your ADC. Values 0-1023 would indicate a 10-bit ADC, and the range is the minimum to maximum quantity that the ADC is converting. With a photo resistor, you are likely forcing a current and reading the voltage.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a voltage (analogRead(lightPin)). You can convert your [ADC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) reading to a voltage by this process:

```
percent = (adcNumber / MaxADC)
voltage = percent * MaxVoltage
```

So for you

```
 voltage = (data1/ 1023.0)* 5.0
```

You are reading voltage, but the voltage is changing, because the "resistance" of your photoresistor is changing.

If you are using a voltage divider then this equation

```
vout = R1/(R1+R2) * vin
```

But I can't give you an equation to calculate the resistance or current without more information on the circuit.

Comment: Yes, essentially we would need to know if the photo-resistor is R1 (to ground) or R2 (to supply) and what presumably fixed resistor is the other.  And if you want to convert it back to something in terms of light, we'd need curves (and tolerances) for the photo resistor from its data sheet.

Comment: Okay, That makes sense. Values are coming in at ~4V when sensor is completely covered. And down to 1V when hit with laser. Updating question with hardware details.

Comment: Remember that light level and voltage may not have a linear relationship, and different wavelengths may produce different voltages even at the same intensity. Without the data sheet, it may be difficult to tell without calibrated light levels.